# window.location.href on enter press returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enter a value in a search box and press the enter key to redirect it to `/workers/VALUE`

Currently it redirects to `workers/undefined`

Am I referencing the wrong class in the var product?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // enter pressed
      var product = $("#search-box").val();
      window.location.href = "/workers/" + product;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="nav-item hidden-sm-down search-box">
  <a class="nav-link hidden-sm-down text-muted waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <i class="ti-search"></i>
  </a>
  <form class="app-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-box" placeholder="Search Wallet Address">
    <a class="srh-btn">
      <i class="ti-close"></i>
    </a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Comment: var product = $("input.search-box").val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend you use window.location, but your error is in your html, you forgot the id of your input.

```
<input type="text" id="search-box" class="form-control search-box" placeholder="Search Wallet Address">
```

Or try use the class

```
$(".search-box")
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend using `window.location`?

Comment: Sorry, in this scenario i think that does not have problem

Comment: I still wonder why you wouldn't use `window.location`... Is there a reason that's wrong to use or is that only in particular use cases?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an `id`, but your search box only has that id as a `class`, so replace this:

```
$("#search-box")
```

with this:

```
$("input.search-box")
```

Comment: @klabranche Jup, didn't see that other class reference there. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is looking for an element with ID equals to 'search-box', which does not exist.

You could Use `$(".search-box").get(0).val();` to select the first element with a certain class, but in your case, the *li* element also has this same class, so this code would not work as well (as pointed to me by @somethinghere comment below).

To remove the ambiguity you will be better off using the ID selector, so just use `$("#search-box").val()`and add the ID to the input element like below:

```
<input id="search-box" type="text" class="form-control search-box" placeholder="Search Wallet Address">
```

Comment: Like somebody commented on mine, this will actually select the wrong element as the parent has the same class.

Comment: @somethinghere, you're right, I didn't see that, thanks. So the best option would be to use an ID and retrieve the element with `$("#search-box"), as it removes the ambiguity

Comment: Yeah or just look for an actual `input` with that class and at least `value()` will always be at least a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the search-box wrongly in your JavaScript.

You should use `var product = $(".search-box").val();`, since you set search-box as a class, and not an id. [Here is a quick reference on CSS selectors which might help](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, you should set the search-box class only on the element you want to reference (the input), since it seems you set it on the list item element as well as the input element.

Comment: Like somebody commented on mine, this will actually select the wrong element as the parent has the same class.

Comment: That is true, hence my advice that you should set the selector only on the element you want to reference. using `input.search-box` works, but you're still going to have another element with a class it shouldn't have. Keeping selectors unique helps make the code more understandable IMO. @somethinghere

Comment: I agree, to a point, but it does make it less reusable. But true, in this case the id would be better.